# I screwed up with my Kwikset lock during rekeying

Tags: lock

I bought a Kwikset rekey kit to rekey the locks at home. However, at the beginning I did not turn the lock to "lock" position; instead, it was in unlocked position. I then followed the instructions given with the kit.

In the end, it turned out that I could not open the lock with either my current and new keys. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to fix it.  You need to essentially disassemble the lock and line the pins up.  Here's a video explaining how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQjXl78DdUA

Comment: Part 2 of the video is how to disassemble and reassemble your automatic transmission.  :-)

Comment: Having done it once, it's not that hard.  It sounds hard, though.

Comment: I have had to do this ... a few times. To be honest, don't blame yourself. I found that the reviews on the rekeying tool are awful. There is a black one and a red one, either way, I returned mine. When I need to rekey and the key is missing, I follow the general approach in the video. Advice, do it over a hard surface, and while most of the videos dont say this, let gravity be your friend. Once you get into it, you'll understand. Holding it in an orientation where gravity isnt moving parts is (pun intended) key.

Comment: Thank you so much guy! Thanks for the video, encourage and experience sharing. I feel frustrated when I made this mistake, but now I am ready to give it another try!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

The video recommended above definitely worked I’m a 30yr old woman that knows nothing about home improvement or fixing things and I managed to fix my mistake using that video. BE VERY CAREFUL the pieces are very small and well fall out when you take the lock apart to reset it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQjXl78DdUA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136754)